# Were there bears at the Treblinka Zoo?

Tags: history, holocaust

I am doing a history project on the Treblinka extermination camp for school, and learnt about the zoo

[image]

Investigating further I found that the zoo contained at least four foxes, two peacocks and a roe deer<sup>[1]</sup>. The following photo is from Kurt Franz's photo album which was displayed in court during his trial

[image]

However the following image keeps appearing:

[image]

[This site](https://furtherglory.wordpress.com/2012/12/30/the-buchenwald-concentration-camp-and-the-treblinka-extermination-camp-both-had-a-zoo/) claims the photo is of Treblinka and that the image also appeared in Franz's album.

However on a more convincing note, the same site has a similar post with [this reply](https://furtherglory.wordpress.com/2012/12/31/the-treblinka-zoo/#comment-13743) suggesting that the photo is actually from the Buchenwald zoo.

Can anyone find a definite answer of wear that photo is from?

---

<sup>1 - see [Dam im imię na wieki](http://echomatkibozejniepokalaniepoczetej.com/embnp/pages/assets/files/2011-09/dam_ime_na_wieki.pdf), p. 78 (in Polish)</sup>

Comment: There was no concentration camp in Treblinka. I think you mean death camp. And note that the website to which you link ("Further Glory") is written by a Holocaust denier and is full of deliberate misinformation. For details on the zoo at Treblinka, I would start with Yitzhak Arad's *Belzec, Sobibor, Treblinka: The Operation Reinhard Death Camps*, and follow his references.

Comment: @ShimonbM it was a labour camp to begin with but it changed to death camp halfway through the way, Thanks for telling me about the site

Comment: Trablinka II, which is where the zoo was located was built from the start as an extermination camp and never was used as a labour camp.